# How to read pixel data from a com.sun.jna.Memory object efficiently

Tags: java, opengl-es-2.0, jna, vlcj

I'm using [vlcj](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) to play videos on a Linux machine, rendering the output via OpenGL ES 2.0.

The incoming pixel data from the video decoder is in a [com.sun.jna.Memory](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Memory.html) object.

So far I've got the 'pipeline' of pixel data to the OpenGL texture as this:

```
@Override
public void display( DirectMediaPlayer mediaPlayer, Memory[] nativeBuffer, BufferFormat format )
{
    ....
    IntBuffer pixelBuffer = nativeBuffer.getByteBuffer( 0L, nativeBuffer.size() ).asIntBuffer();
    ....
}
```

I keep the reference to pixelBuffer in another object, then throw the pixelBuffer reference into a [glTexSubImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml) call when I'm ready to display the frame.

My worry is whether this is the most efficient way to do this? It works but it might be ugly or costly if it is duplicating the data as opposed to simply getting a pointer to the original data contained in the Memory object.

Another aspect is if LibVLC was able to use hardware acceleration then this memory may be in VRAM on the GPU - would a function like this mean the data was pulled back over the BUS to RAM?

Any verdicts? Advice? Prior experience? Alternatives?

Thank you.

Comment: The vlcj-javafx sample project shows one way to do this, but yes, it does more memory copies each frame than are desirable. Ideally, you want the texture to point to the Memory address pointer, but I know next to nothing about OGL.

Comment: I'll take a look at the sample, thanks you. I'm hoping in a ideal world that if the LibVLC back end managed to give you hardware accelerated decoding then the video data would be in VRAM on the GPU, and you can buffer the data into an OpenGL texture - also in VRAM - so there wouldn't be lots of data going over the BUS to RAM & back again. We'll keep playing & see what we can come up with. I don't suppose you know what prerequisites govern LibVLC giving you hardware acceleration in a Linux environment?

Comment: NIO buffers were created for this purpose. JNA treats it the same as `Memory`, but the JVM has built-in operations for NIO buffers to make Java interaction with the buffer more efficient.

Comment: @technomage I can allocate a NIO buffer in Java, and pass to native code via JNA's Memory class?

Comment: The `Pointer` class provides a `getByteBuffer()` to give you NIO access to any `Memory` as an NIO buffer (including arbitrary native pointers).  Alternatively you can create a direct byte buffer through other means (e.g. `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`).